# Shell Script Error

Tags: bash, scripts

First, my desktop environment is GNOME.
I made a script to make an autostart program's desktop file.
However, I got error.

```
Make Autostart Script
Name > nabi // I input nabi
./make_autostart_script: line 11: ~./config/autostart/nabi.desktop: No such file or directory
Descriptive Name >
```

And the code is

```
# !/bin/bash
# This script make autostart script

echo Make Autostart Script

# Name
echo -n "Name > "
read name
touch ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop
echo "[Desktop Entry]" >> ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop
echo "Name=$name" >> ~./config/autostart/$name.desktop

# Generic Name
echo -n "Descriptive Name > "
read generic_name
echo "GenericName=$generic_name" >> ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop

# Comment
echo -n "Comment > "
read comment
echo "Comment=$comment" >> ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop

# Exec
echo -n "Location of program > "
read exec
echo "Exec=$exec" >> ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop

# Terminal
echo -n "Do you want to execute it in terminal?(Y/n) > "
read yn
if [$yn -eq y];then
        echo "Terminal=true" >> ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop
else
        echo "Terminal=false">> ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop
fi

# Type
echo "Type=Application" >> ~/.config/autostart/$name/desktop

# Autostart
echo "X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true"
```

How can i fix the problem?

Comment: run it via `bash -x scriptname`

Comment: It's just a typo I think - should be `~/.config` not `~./config`

Comment: Also,  you should have the first line be `#!/bin/bash` rather than just a comment such as `# !/bin/bash`

Comment: Do #!/bin/bash and # !/bin/bash have difference?

Answer (score 3):

The `~./config` in that line should be `~/.config`

Answer (score 2):

Issue shown in context:

```
# Name
echo -n "Name > "
read name
touch ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop
echo "[Desktop Entry]" >> ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop
echo "Name=$name" >> ~./config/autostart/$name.desktop
```

should be:

```
# Name
echo -n "Name > "
read name
touch ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop
echo "[Desktop Entry]" >> ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop
echo "Name=$name" >> ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop
```

with the change being ( bold for emphasis ):

`echo "Name=$name" >>`**~/.**`config/autostart/$name.desktop`

which points to a folder called `.config` which is in your home directory ( `~` for short )

rather than:

`echo "Name=$name" >>`**~./**`config/autostart/$name.desktop`

which points to a non-existent directory called `~.` ( unless you had a user named `.` , in which it would point to `.`'s home folder )

*As a side note as well:*

It appears that you will encounter an error at section *# Type*.

```
# Type
echo "Type=Application" >> ~/.config/autostart/$name/desktop
```

should be

```
# Type
echo "Type=Application" >> ~/.config/autostart/$name.desktop
```

if I am not mistaken. (the difference is replacing `$name/desktop` with `$name.desktop`

As to the line 31:

`if [$yn -eq y];then` should be at the least `if [ $yn = y ]; then`
but probably more properly

```
if [ "$yn" = "y" ] || [ "$yn" = "Y" ];then
```

which would cover if you type Y or y. Take a note that using `-eq` is for numeral comparisons, and will not work in this case.

Hope that helps! Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for point out #type's error, but I got a new error on line 31.

Comment: proper spacing is your friend.   `if [$yn -eq y];then` needs to become `if [ "$yn" = "y" ]; then`   and it is also smart to either sanitize the input or make sure you do not shoot yourself in the foot with user input. I added quotes as well on the test conditions. Also note that this will only allow for input of y and not Y.... be careful.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as solved :)